# why I can't define a function like fun(**kwargs, *args)?

Tags: python

args always before kwargs when many python book introduce them. I just swap the position of them, but the interpreter told me this is a invalid syntax. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: What exactly would the benefit of this be?

Comment: Do you understand what they are, and how they work?

Comment: Honestly I don't think there's a deeper reason besides "there should only be one obvious way to do something", thus making it easier to mentally parse what parameter will get what value for a given function call.

Comment: @millimoose not sure about your comment on Tim's (now deleted post) - see: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments (using `func(a=1, 'bob')` will be an invalid call syntax)

Comment: @JonClements It was a hypothetical, speculating on what the OP's proposed syntax might allow. (A more flexible - and IMO more inscrutable way of matching provides params to the signature.)

Comment: @millimoose That'd make more sense then. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 10):

It is against the syntax of Python to define positional arguments after keyword arguments. Thus how should it make sense for you to define a function that first accepts a dictionary of keyword parameters and then a tuple of positional parameters?

For an explanation of the rationale behind the rule, imagine if you were writing a compiler for Python that was supposed to translate a given script into bytecode.

Suppose you have a function:

```
def func(a, b=2, c=3):
    print a,b,c
```

then someone calls that function with:

```
func(c=1,b=2,3)
```

Do you see the ambiguity? How are you supposed to tell if the programmer meant to assign that last '3' to the last leftover argument 'a' or if he *meant* to assign it to 'c' but simply made a typo with `c=1` and actually meant `a=1`. If you were writing syntax rules for any language, wouldn't you want to explicitly define a set of rules so that you could be *absolutely sure* what the programmer wanted to do instead of guessing what the programmer wanted to do?

Sure I guess there is [Interlisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlisp) and other arcane languages out there that attempt to "guess" what the programmer is trying to do but Python is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the concept of named parameters is conflated with the concept of optional parameters. When you define your function with optional arguments like `def drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color=Color.BLACK, width=1)` all the optional arguments have to come at the end of the list - otherwise, if you have more than one optional argument, it would be ambiguous which value was an optional argument versus a required argument. If you then invoke drawLine with `drawLine(x1=1, x2=2, 3,4,1)`, which arguments go with which? So for sanity's sake, put the positional arguments first, followed by the named arguments. Declaring *args and **kwargs in the same order just makes sense from a conceptual consistency standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually defined very explicitly in the [documentation](http://www.python.org/doc//current/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) (my emphasis):

> In general, an argument list **must have any positional arguments
>   followed by any keyword arguments**, where the keywords must be chosen
>   from the formal parameter names. It’s not important whether a formal
>   parameter has a default value or not. No argument may receive a value
>   more than once — formal parameter names corresponding to positional
>   arguments cannot be used as keywords in the same calls.
>
> [...]
>
> When a final formal parameter of the form `**name` is present, it
>   receives a dictionary containing all keyword arguments except for
>   those corresponding to a formal parameter. This may be combined with a
>   formal parameter of the form `*name` (described in the next
>   subsection) which receives a tuple containing the positional arguments
>   beyond the formal parameter list. **(`*name` must occur before
>   `**name`.)**

Comment: This is merely an authoritative citation for the restriction, not an explanation of the rationale.

Comment: Well the [BDFL has an account here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum) so maybe he'll chime in.

Comment: There need not be a rationale any deeper than "that's how it is". I could ask a question similar to the OP "Why is `while = foo` a syntax error?" which would be a patently silly question.

Comment: One possible rationale - since positional arguments are required (and keyword arguments optional), the order is given the same precedence.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I haven't gone through his whole answer history or anything, but I've never seen him answer a question about the reasons for design decisions. Ask a specific question about using appengine's `ndb` module, otoh, and he'll be all over it.

Comment: Since when are positional parameters in the sense of `*args` required? `print()` works just fine for me in Python 3.2...

Comment: @Wooble I think now to get his attention the questions will have to do with Dropbox APIs ;)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That's because print has no required arguments `def print(*args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None)` ([`PEP-3105`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#specification))

Comment: Exactly. `*args` denotes optional arguments. So the point about positional parameters being required doesn't matter here because `*args` arguments aren't required. The question is specifically about `*args` and `**kwargs`, not any other sort of parameters.

Comment: It denotes optional _positional arguments_. Since they are required if defined, my guess was that is what defined the syntax (the order of it). However Shashank's answer seems more plausible.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's my best guess so far. For obvious reasons (ambiguity), *required* positional parameters have to come before "required" keyword parameters (positional parameters with defaults) in the parameter signature and the call, so it makes sense to require the same order for the optional parameters.